# how to use ArrayField with ImageField in rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i have a list of images for a every object, but can not use it.

models:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    national_card = ArrayField(
        models.ImageField(upload_to=directory_path), blank=True, null=True,
)
```

serializer:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

database (column of national_card):

```
{
    orders/2d4ba9ff-44af-44e9-9203-a0aad5a3c7ec/380cbbf0-1b73-4e36-996d-015c81dbaa71.jpg,
    orders/2d4ba9ff-44af-44e9-9203-a0aad5a3c7ec/380cbbf0-1b73-4e36-996d-015c81dbaa71.jpg
}
```

result of serializer:

```
{
    "national_card": [
         null, null
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayField` and `FileField` (`ImageField`, ...) is not compatible. and not work correctly. (can not copy file to `upload_to`)

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25756

but,

```
{
    "national_card": [
        null, null
    ]
}
```

This output has no connection to it! But because of multiple inheritance. and one of them bad effect to it.